# how to make multiple activity independantly of each other

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm just starting to make an android app and i'm already stuck. I would like to have multiple tabs, which are using an activity containing a listview, the data in a listview for each tab are supposed to be different in each tab. Do i have to make multiple activity files and multiple layouts with differents ID ?

for exemple : tab 1 containing listview with data ( A, B )
              tab 2 containing listview with data ( C,D,E)
              tab 3 containing listview with data ( F )

(P.S: the app i'm trying to make is an ordering app for a restaurant) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You should use Fragments, heres a link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html, and heres example: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/